# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

```
package pack;


public class sample{ 

 public static void main(String input[])
    {

        NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00##");
    System.out.println(numberFormat.format(44533125.00));

    } 
}
```

the code is working fine in the current dir.. (c:/myprogram/).

after that i copy the sample.class file and paste it in other dir(d:/myprogram).
i got error while running, like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sample (wrong name: pack/sample)
```

In java .class file can run anywhere right? but why i am not able to run?

Comment: why is this a community wiki!??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should have the class file within the package - so it should be in a directory called `pack`. Then with the parent directory in the classpath, you'd run

```
java pack.sample
```

(You should also change the class name to Sample to follow conventions, btw - and run `pack.Sample`.)

If you're building with javac, specify the "-d" option to tell it the base directory, and it will create the appropriate package structure if necessary. For example:

```
javac -d classes Sample.java
```

or

```
javac -d classes src/pack/Sample.java
```

will (in both cases) create

```
classes/pack/Sample.class
```

You could then run

```
java -cp classes pack.Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ and maybe other IDE's do not refactor your Run/Debug configuration. You must manually change your package name preceding the name of your Main class. For instance, change 'sample.Main' to 'com.company.package.ui.Main' so it will launch correctly next time you try to run it. 
The IDE might have already marked the Run/Debug button with a red cross because it couldn't find the main class. It also gives a warning when you open the Run/Debug configuration.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using a single java/class file you can also remove the package statement.